# MySQL: Query with UUID (bytestring) as primary key not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, innodb, uuid

I have a table in a MySQL database, that uses UUID v1 as the primary key.
The UUIDs are stored optimized, as a 16-byte string, as described in https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/ .
The MYSQL data type for the column is binary(16). All UUIDs are generated the same way, using a PHP library. MySQL is v5.0.12.

I retrieve rows from the table like this:

```
$where = sprintf("'%s'", $bytestring_uuid);

$wpdb->get_results(
                            "
                                SELECT *
                                FROM $my_table
                                WHERE id = $where 
                            "
            );
```

Now this usually works, but oddly, with some UUIDs the query fails and i can't figure out why.

Here are some UUIDs the query works with (in the original format, so you can read them) :

```
c80615fc-e441-11e8-b328-002522a6b241

d4c94f0c-e441-11e8-9316-002522a6b241

df11cade-e441-11e8-b3a5-002522a6b241
```

This one fails:

```
27c049c4-e67f-11e8-9e6f-002522a6b241
```

Error log:

> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '?IÄžo' at line 3 for query
>                                   SELECT *
>                                   FROM my_table
>                                   WHERE id = 'èäAÈü³(

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Your code also looks prone to SQL injections at first seight..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

27 is single quote, 22 is double quote.  Hence a serious need to escape the binary string.  Yes, that link tells you how to take only 16 bytes for storing it.

Or...  Instead of saying

```
WHERE uuid = '?IÄžo...'
```

capture the hex and say

```
WHERE uuid = UNHEX('27c049c4e67f11...');
```

That is, have `$byte_string` be 32 hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

Solving your SQL injection problem will also solve that some characters in a binary format don't expand nicely in a PHP interpolated string.

Using a [PDO or mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) solution will fix both of your problems.

Also MySQL-5.0.12 that is so far out of any maintained state. You will run into troubles where the only solution is to upgrade. Sooner the better.